# How to change indentation/margin of table in Context?

Tags: tables, indentation, context

This is the code I use to create a simple table in Context:

```
\starttable[|lw(43mm)|lw(43mm)|]

\NC {\em Mer uttalade} \NC {\em Mindre uttalade} \NC\AR
\NC {\em bearbetningsegenskaper} \NC {\em bearbetningsegenskaper} \NC\AR
\HL
\NC svetsad metall \NC gjuten metall \NC\AR
\NC handformad gips \NC gjuten gips \NC\AR

\stoptable
```

[Please see this image of what it looks like!](http://tiny-img.com/di-Y7KV.jpg)

Note the difference in the level of indentation of the table (or call it margin if you will) -- this is marked with red pencil.

How do I affect the size of this indentation? I would like it to be smaller.

I've been trying different things like `\setupindenting`, but can't affect this space in any way. Would be thankful for any suggestions!

Comment: What you see is not indentation, but the offset for each column. Use `s0` as the first column specifier to get rid of it. See the last example on http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Table

Comment: For more control on the space, see Sec 7 of http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb29-1/tb91mahajan.pdf

Answer (score 2):

From my [TugBoat article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb29-1/tb91mahajan.pdf) on tables:

> By default, there is a `0.5em` (usually about half the current font size) space between the columns. We can change this using the `o` and the `s` keys. The `o` key changes the space on the right of the current column; the `s` key changes the space of all the following columns until the next `o` or `s` key.
>
> There are two ways of specifying the parameters of the `o` and `s` keys. The ﬁrst is in integer multiples of `0.5em`: `s{n}` makes the space equal to `n`
> times `0.5em`. So, to get a space of `1.5em` between columns we can use `\starttable[s{3}|l|l|]`. The second way is to specify the distance as an arbitrary TEX dimension. So, we could also have used `\starttable[s(1.5em)|l|l|]`. Notice that in the ﬁrst case, the argument is given in curly brackets; in the second, the argument is given in parentheses.

Thus, to remove the space from the beginning of the first column, add `o0` in the first column specifier (one **before** the first `|`); to remove the space from the last column add `s0` in the last column specifier (one **before** the last `|`).

```
\starttext
\starttable[o0|lw(43mm)|lw(43mm)s0|]
\NC {\em Mer uttalade} \NC {\em Mindre uttalade} \NC\AR
\NC {\em bearbetningsegenskaper} \NC {\em bearbetningsegenskaper} \NC\AR
\HL
\NC svetsad metall \NC gjuten metall \NC\AR
\NC handformad gips \NC gjuten gips \NC\AR
\stoptable
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Note that the `table` mechanism is the oldest table mechanisms for ConTeXt. A more versatile table mechanism is `TABLE` (`\bTABLE ...` \eTABLE`or for simple tables, its shortcut`\startTABLE ... `\stopTABLE`). Using the `TABLE` mechanism you can get the same effect as follows:

```
\startsetups table:frames
  \setupTABLE[frame=off]
  \setupTABLE[row][2][bottomframe=on]
\stopsetups
\starttext
\startTEXpage
\startTABLE[setups={table:frames}]
\NC {\em Mer uttalade} \NC {\em Mindre uttalade} \NC\NR
\NC {\em bearbetningsegenskaper} \NC {\em bearbetningsegenskaper} \NC\NR
\NC svetsad metall \NC gjuten metall \NC\NR
\NC handformad gips \NC gjuten gips \NC\NR
\stopTABLE
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

[image]

(The defaults are different for the two mechanisms, and therefore the tables look different visually).

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative answer + link to interesting article! I will try this now, and move my `table` to `TABLE` :)